# How to sort "chapter numbers" like 1.1.1, 1.2.1, 1.2.46, etc.?

Tags: ruby, sorting

Is there a quick way to sort "chapter numbers" in Ruby?

```
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2.1
1.3.1
1.3.2
1.3.3
10.42.64
etc.?
```

Do I have to write an enumerator or something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby, `Array`s are ordered lexicographically, so the easiest way would be to convert these into `Array`s and then sort them:

```
chapters = %w[1.1.1 1.1.2 1.2.1 1.3.1 1.3.2 1.3.3 10.42.64]

chapters.sort_by {|chapter| chapter.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
# => ["1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.2.1", "1.3.1", "1.3.2", "1.3.3", "10.42.64"]
```

Of course, the *real* solution would be to use objects instead of slugging around arrays of strings of numbers. After all, Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an arrays-of-strings-of-numbers-oriented language:

```
class ChapterNumber
  include Comparable

  def initialize(*nums)
    self.nums = nums
  end

  def <=>(other)
    nums <=> other.nums
  end

  def to_s
    nums.join('.')
  end

  alias_method :inspect, :to_s

  protected

  attr_reader :nums

  private

  attr_writer :nums
end

chapters = [ChapterNumber.new(1, 1, 1), ChapterNumber.new(1, 1, 2), 
  ChapterNumber.new(1, 2, 1), ChapterNumber.new(1, 3, 1), 
  ChapterNumber.new(1, 3, 2), ChapterNumber.new(1, 3, 3), 
  ChapterNumber.new(10, 42, 64)]

chapters.sort
# => [1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 10.42.64]
```

Comment: `%w[1.1.1 1.1.2 1.2.1 1.3.1 1.3.2 1.3.3 10.42.64].map &ChapterNumber.method(:new)` looks more DRY :)

Comment: I thought about whether `initialize` should take a list of integers or a string, but I settled for integers.

Comment: Yes, I see. Then probably `split` and then map `to_i` is still more DRY. Anyway, upvoted already.

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you. There's still a lot to learn, I see.

Answer (score 0):

```
(l: string, r: string) => {
    const left = l.split('.');
    const right = r.split('.');

    let count = Math.max(left.length, right.length);

    let idx = 0;

    while (idx < count) {
        const lValue = parseInt((left[idx] || '0'));
        const rValue = parseInt((right[idx] || '0'));
        if (lValue === rValue) {
            idx++
        } else {
            return lValue < rValue ? -1 : lValue > rValue ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
};
```